# How to read Article pages Title & Description from page Library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, caml-query

In C# code get Article pages Title & Description from page Library...

For this I used below code:-

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("siteUrl");
clientContext.Credentials = cred;
var contentTypeId ="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D";
var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();               
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>"+contentTypeId+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
 {
   Event item = new Event();
   item.Title = oListItem["Title"].ToString();
   E1.Add(item);
 }
```

Comment: what's the issue here ? for description, you can use `Convert.ToString(oListItem["Comments"]);` which is the OOTB field or if you  have custom field you can use that

Comment: In collListItem count get 0.but In Pages Library I created 5 Article pages.

Comment: Looks like issue with content type id value. Try this caml query: `camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>"+contentTypeId+"</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";` or change the content type id to `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D00E4823458F34FF84EBBF6A21D1ABA5C6F` and check

Comment: Not worked above query